# Scala: avoiding cast to type parameter in foldLeft

Tags: scala, casting, fold

Consider this snippet defining a trait for the state of a simulation, which a user is expected to implement in some derived type. On the trait, a collection of utility methods should be able to provide results that have the type of the implementation, similar to the way the Scala library collections do this. To achieve that, I think I need to parameterize the trait with the implementation type, like this:

```
trait State[+This <: State[This]] {
   def update : This  // result has type of State's implementor
}
```

Now I would like to define a multi-step update method, like this:

```
def update(steps: Int) : This
```

When I try the naive approach:

```
def update(steps: Int) : This = 
    (this /: (0 until steps))( (s,n) => s.update )
```

the compiler complains about a type mismatch:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found: State[This]
 required: This
```

which makes sense, since `this`, seen within State, has type State[This]. 
To get the code to compile, it seems I have to do an explicit cast:

```
def update(steps: Int) : This = 
    (this.asInstanceOf[This] /: (0 until steps))( (s,n) => s.update )
```

Is there a way to avoid this explicit cast, or more generally to achieve the intended result in a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a self-type annotation to ensure that `State` is a `This`:

```
trait State[+This <: State[This]] { this: This =>
  def update: This  // result has type of State's implementor
}
```

A possible way to redefine the `update(Int)` method without a fold would be:

```
def update(steps: Int): This = Iterator.iterate(this)(_.update).drop(steps).next
```